# simple(?) PIVOT without an aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Pivots, man...I'm just missing it. Maybe it's because I'm not doing an aggregate. Heck, maybe a pivot isn't the way to do this. It feels like it should be simple, but it's got me stumped.

Let's say I've got this:

```
SELECT col1
FROM tbl1

col1
====
414
589
```

How can I get these two records back as:

```
fauxfield1  fauxfield2
==========  ==========
414         589
```

Couple of caveats for the purposes of this question

- I'm **never** going to get back more than two records
- I'm always going to get back integers, but *I don't know what they will be*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `PIVOT` operator:

```
select [1] as field1,
  [2] as field2
from
(
  select col1, row_number() Over(order by col1) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(col1)
  for rn in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72c42/2)

Comment: Solid Gold! Took me a bit to puzzle out what you were doing with the row_number. Thanks so much!

Comment: Follow up - How do I do this in SQL 2000 without the ranking functions (like row_number)?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2000?  If so, then there is no `PIVOT` function or windowing functions like `row_number()` and you will have to use one of the other answers to get your result.

Answer (score 2):

If you're *only ever* going to have 2 values, you could do it like this

```
select
    (select top(1) col1 from tbl1 order by col1) fauxfield1,
    (select top(1) col1 from tbl1 order by col1 desc) fauxfield2;
```

What I don't understand however is why there is a need to avoid aggregates? Have you found some crippled version of SQL Server?  The normal query would be

```
select min(col1) fauxfield1, max(col1) fauxfield2
  from tbl1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're only getting two, why not this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(col1) ff1
    , CASE MAX(col1) 
        WHEN MIN(col1) THEN NULL
        ELSE MAX(col1)
      END ff2
FROM 
    tbl1;
```

This only shows a second value if there are two.