# SQL Dynamic Pivot without aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I have found some thing similar to what I need, but I can't wrap my brain around how to take it where it needs to go.

This helped for sure: [simple(?) PIVOT without an aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750667/simple-pivot-without-an-aggregate)

---

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT  [1] AS Lien1
   ,[2] AS Lien2
   ,[3] AS Lien3
   ,[4] AS Lien4
   ,[5] AS Lien5
   ,[6] AS Lien6
FROM    ( SELECT    lt.Name AS [LienName]
            --   ,LienID 
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LienID ) AS RN
      FROM      dbo.Lien AS L
                INNER JOIN dbo.LienType AS LT ON LT.LienTypeID = L.LienTypeID
      WHERE     FileID = 528267
    ) AS PivotSource PIVOT

( MAX(LienName) FOR RN IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6] ) ) piv
```

Which returns the following results:

```
Lien1   Lien2   Lien3   Lien4   Lien5   Lien6
Deed of Trust   Assignment  Appointment of Substitute Trustee   Assignment  Assignment  Civil Foreclosure Case
```

---

I need the commented line (-- LienID) to not be commented out and return the LienID after the corresponding LienName like (I removed the last four columns for formatting purposes).

```
Lien1            LienID Lien2        LienID    
Deed of Trust    123    Assignment   234
```

---

Maybe Pivot isn't the best way to do this, but it's the best that I have found thus far. I have 5 tables that return multiple rows that I need to return all the values on one row. I have been trying to understand the dynamic SQL Pivot questions on here, but I haven't been able to execute one to perform the way I need it to perform.

I am open to any and all suggestions that would help - thanks in advance for your time!

---

EDIT: 11/4/14 @10:47AM

I wanted to come back and post the work in progress since I've turned this answer into some what of a dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @FileID INT = 528267 
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF((SELECT   ',' + QUOTENAME('LienNumber' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SortOrder )))
                   FROM     dbo.Lien AS L
                            INNER JOIN dbo.LienType AS LT ON LT.LienTypeID = L.LienTypeID
                            INNER JOIN dbo.FileActions AS FA ON fa.FileID = l.FileID
                                                                AND fa.ActionDefID = 1184
                                                                AND fa.SentDate IS NOT NULL
                                                                AND fa.ReceivedDate IS NULL
                                                                AND fa.FileID = @FileID
    FOR           XML PATH('')
                     ,TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')



SET @Query = 'DECLARE @FileID INT = 528267  SELECT  ' + @cols + '
      FROM (select   lt.name as Name, ''LienNumber'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SortOrder )) as RN
     FROM

         dbo.Lien AS L
                INNER JOIN dbo.LienType AS LT ON LT.LienTypeID = L.LienTypeID
                INNER JOIN dbo.FileActions AS FA ON fa.FileID = l.FileID
                                                    AND fa.ActionDefID = 1184
                                                    AND fa.SentDate IS NOT NULL
                                                    AND fa.ReceivedDate IS NULL
                                                              AND fa.FileID = @FileID

                                              ) x
                                             pivot (       MAX(name) FOR RN IN ( ' + @Cols + ' ) ) p'




EXEC (@query)
```

---

With the help of: [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: When you say _return the LienID after the corresponding LienName._ what does that mean? What should the results look like?

Comment: just posted - thanks!

Comment: Huh, could you set up a set of sample data on sqlfiddle? The idea I have should work, but would prefer to have a live engine to test on before editing my answer.

Comment: Yes I will post it for you in SQLFiddle, Jaaz.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e693/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your desired output correct I think this query should do it, please give it a try:

```
SELECT
    Lien1   = MAX([1]), 
    LienID  = MAX([r1]),
    Lien2   = MAX([2]),
    LienID  = MAX([r2]), 
    Lien3   = MAX([3]),
    LienID  = MAX([r3]),
    Lien4   = MAX([4]),
    LienID  = MAX([r4]),
    Lien5   = MAX([5]),
    LienID  = MAX([r5]),
    Lien6   = MAX([6]),
    LienID  = MAX([r6])
FROM ( 
    SELECT
       lt.Name AS [LienName]
       ,LienID 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LienID ) AS RN1
        ,'r'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LienID ) AS varchar(10)) AS RN2
    FROM Lien AS L
    INNER JOIN LienType AS LT ON LT.LienTypeID = L.LienTypeID
    WHERE FileID = 528267
    ) AS PivotSource 
PIVOT ( MAX(LienName) FOR RN1 IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6] ) ) as names
PIVOT ( MAX(LienID)   FOR RN2 IN ( [r1], [r2], [r3], [r4],[r5],[r6] ) ) as ids
```

Comment: That's it! That's depressing because now I realize what I need to do to satisfy my client and it makes me want to cry. That being said, I need to take this a step further and some how make it dynamic. The example that I used had 6 rows returned but in reality, it could be more or less. Thanks JPW!

Comment: @jessicak. It should be easy to make the query dynamic, I can look at it later.

Comment: I just figured it out, I think. It's probably the ugliest thing I've ever written in my life, but if it saves someone 25 hours a week on the floor, the code can be as ugly as it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there on this. Another copy of the query, pivoted on ID, then joined again by fileID should do the trick. Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e693/14).

```
SELECT
   a.FileID
  ,a.Lien1
  ,b.LienID1
  ,a.Lien2
  ,b.LienID2
  ,a.Lien3
  ,b.LienID3
  ,a.Lien4
  ,b.LienID4
  ,a.Lien5
  ,b.LienID5
  ,a.Lien6
  ,b.LienID6
FROM (
  SELECT
      FileID
     ,[1] AS Lien1
     ,[2] AS Lien2
     ,[3] AS Lien3
     ,[4] AS Lien4
     ,[5] AS Lien5
     ,[6] AS Lien6
  FROM    ( SELECT
                  FileID
                 ,LienName
                 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LienID ) AS RN
        FROM      dbo.Lien AS L

        WHERE     FileID = 528267
      ) AS PivotSource
  PIVOT ( MAX(LienName) FOR RN IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6] ) ) piv1
  ) a
  INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
      FileID
     ,[1] AS LienID1
     ,[2] AS LienID2
     ,[3] AS LienID3
     ,[4] AS LienID4
     ,[5] AS LienID5
     ,[6] AS LienID6
  FROM    ( SELECT
                  FileID
                 ,LienID 
                 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LienID ) AS RN
        FROM      dbo.Lien AS L

        WHERE     FileID = 528267
      ) AS PivotSource
  PIVOT ( MAX(LienID) FOR RN IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6] ) ) piv1
  ) b ON a.FileID = b.FileID
```

Comment: While this does select the Lien, ID it wasn't exactly what I was going for - but that's my fault for not posting a sample of what it should look like, which I am going to do now.